# WinDbg fails to connect to IDA Pro debugger server

Tags: windows, ida, debuggers, kernel-mode, windbg

Environment:

- Host: Win7 SP1 x64: VMWare Workstation 9.02, VirtualKD, IDA Pro 6.4.13 (x64) and WinDbg
- Guest: Win7 SP1 x64

I have VirtualKD setup correctly in my guest and host.
I say this because attaching WinDbg to the guest VM through VirtualKD works flawlessly.

But when I try to connect IDA Pro's WinDbg interface using instruction on [this page](http://www.hexblog.com/?p=123), IDA keeps throwing the following error:

```
Windbg: using debugging tools from '<PATH>'
Connecting to debugger server with 'com:port=\\.\pipe\kd_Win7x64_SP1,pipe'
Connect failed: The server is currently disabled.
```

VirtualKD's `vmmon` is running on the host and shows the following:[image: vmmon UI]

**UPDATE:** Turns out, It's a problem with IDA 6.4. I happened to have IDA 6.3 installed on my machine too. That worked with no issues.
Has anyone used IDA6.4 for live kernel debugging?
Can someone please tell me how I can correct this issue *in IDA 6.4*?

Comment: welcome to RE.SE. Are you connected with WinDbg *while* you try to connect with IDA?

Comment: No I'm not :) No other debugger is connected to the target at present

Comment: I would strongly recommend using official support channels (i.e. email) for such localized IDA issues.

Comment: Somehow that thought never struck me. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the same problem at first when trying to connect `IDAPro` to `windbg`. What I did was the following:

1. Manually edit the `ida.cfg` file located inside `.\IDA 6.4\cfg\ directory`.
2. Change the `DBGTOOLS` path with WinDbg tools directory. For example, to:

   ```
   DBGTOOLS = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Kits\\8.0\\Debuggers\\x86\\";
   ```

Comment: Just to add,  it should be double backslashed, like in C programming. And make sure you selected Kernel Debugging in Debugger->Debug Options->Specific Debug Options

Comment: Also make sure that you have the 32-bit version of the debugger tools installed - the package is WinSDKDebugToolsRedist_x86 but MS won't install it when you install the debugging tools if you are on a 64-bit system.